# if caption package is loaded autoref doesn't work correctly when using htlatex

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, tex4ht, htlatex, autoref

If I use autoref while the caption package is loaded, the target type does not appear in the reference if I generate html with htlatex. If I use pdflatex, autoref works as expected.

Here's an example document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

See \autoref{tab:example} or \autoref{fig:seahorse}.

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{A Table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l l}
    Col 1   & Col 2 \\
    \hline
    a       & 1 \\
    b       & 2 \\
    c       & 3 \\
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:example}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Seahorse}
\label{fig:seahorse}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{hippocampus.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And this is the output I got with htlatex:

[image]

If I don't import the caption package, the reference is generated with both the target type and the reference number (the text says "See Table 1 or Figure 1").

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is a missing support for the `\autoref` functionality in `caption`'s support in TeX4ht. We need to provide some definitions for each command that sets a new label.

Try this `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\catcode`\:=11
\makeatletter
\pend:defIII\caption@beginex{%
  \gdef\NR:Type{\@currenvir}%
  \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{##2}}%
} 
\makeatother
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The important part is this:

```
\pend:defIII\caption@beginex{%
  \gdef\NR:Type{\@currenvir}%
  \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{##2}}%
}
```

The `\caption@beginex` is internal command that is called by `\caption` with Caption package. We insert two commands for TeX4ht, `\NR:Type` which saves the current environment name and `\NR:Title`. Because `\caption@beginex` takes three parameters, we use the `\pend:defIII` command to patch it.

Compile using:

```
make4ht -c mycfg.cfg filename.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: That works! Thanks for the solution and the explanation.

Comment: @avren that's great! I've already updated TeX4ht sources and the fix should be available in TeX Live, as Mico said

Answer (score 3):

**update 4 Feb 2021** --  @michal.h21, the maintainer of `tex4tht` and the `htlatex` executable, has posted a patch to the CTAN. Tthe problem behavior of `\autoref` is gone.

---

Here's a fix that's not a complete solution, but, rather, a work-around: Don't use the `\autoref` command of the `hyperref` package; instead, use the `\cref` macro of the `cleveref` package. If you pursue this route, be sure to load `cleveref` *after* `hyperref`.

A nice advantage that `\cref` has over `\autoref` is that it can take multiple arguments -- and does a good job sorting the arguments.

The following screenshot shows the output of `\autoref` in line 1 and that of `\cref` in line 2.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{graphicx} % not needed for this MWE
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref} % load this package _last_

\begin{document}
\autoref{tab:example}, \autoref{fig:example}

\cref{tab:example}, \cref{fig:example}; \cref{tab:example,fig:example,tab:example2}

\begin{table}[ht]  \caption{A Table}       \label{tab:example}  \end{table}
\begin{figure}[ht] \caption{A Figure}      \label{fig:example}  \end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]  \caption{Another Table} \label{tab:example2} \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Although it doesn't address the fact that autoref doesn't work with caption, it's an effective workaround.

Comment: @avren  - The `tex4ht` package has been patched in the meantime; the workaround described in my answer is no longer needed.