# make4ht with table environment

Tags: luatex, make4ht

When I have running `pdflatex` it's not showing error and showing error with `make4ht`. How to rectify this? and How to get the `entities` should be `hexadecimal values` instead of `utf`? (Ex: `“` should be `&#x201C;`).

Where to get/see the documentation of `make4ht-domfilter` file?

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{acm-book}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,hyperref,listings,xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[inactive]{fancytooltips}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\begin{document}

\chapter{What is {\textquotedblleft}Software{\textquotedblright}?}

Furthermore, legacy software systems are notoriously difficult to replace. As noted experienced by this author as a chief information officer, legacy systems take considerable effort and money to replace and tend to be built upon, rather than replaced. So, those working on systems for complex organizations are likely to have to deal with these existing software systems. US Social Security Administration still dependencies on legacy software further entrenches its use. Other systems used by the US government have software sub-systems.

\begin{table}[!t]
\caption{\label{tab:4.1}\textbf{MIPS machine code instruction types}}
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline
Instruction Type & opcode &  &  & & & \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{\#bits} & 6 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 6\\
\hline
\hline
R-type & op & rs & rt & rd & shamt & funct\\
\hline
I-type & op & rs & rt & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{address/immediate}\\
\hline
J-type & op & \multicolumn{5}{l|}{target address}  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


When reusing existing software, it is wise to evaluate the relevance of the techniques and assumptions that were used in building that original software. This book focuses on software as a technology and how it has evolved over time. We will look at the trends, important innovations, and events, as well as the ever-broadening world of software.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works for me with 1) the `book` class (I don't have `acm-book`) 2) `\caption{MIPS machine code instruction types}
\label{tab:4.1}` instead of your `\caption` line, and 3) `\arrayrulecolor{black}` commented out (don't ask me why!). The UTF-8 curly quotes look fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a bug in TeX4ht support for the Colortbl package. It assumes that the `\arrayrulecolor` command is used inside `tabular`  or other similar environment. When you use it outside, like in your case, it will break.

The fixed redefinition of the command may look like this:

```
\newcommand\tmp:arrayrulecolor[2][named]{%
\ifvoid\@arstrutbox% test if we are inside a tabular environment
\convertcolorspec{#1}{#2}{HTML}\:tmp\global\let\hline:color\:tmp% we are not
\else%
\noalign{\convertcolorspec{#1}{#2}{HTML}\:tmp\global\let\hline:color\:tmp}% we are
\fi
}
\HLet\arrayrulecolor\tmp:arrayrulecolor
```

This version of `\arrayrulecolor` saves the declared color in the form that is usable in CSS styling for array lines.

The `\ifvoid\@arstrutbox` is used to detect if we are inside tabular, when we need to wrap the color extraction in `\noalign` command to prevent compilation errors.

Here is a full version of `colortbl.4ht`:

```
% colortbl.4ht (2021-05-06-14:12), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 1997-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2021 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2021-05-06-14:12}


   \RequirePackage{xcolor}
\CT@everycr{\o:noalign:{\global\let\CT@row@color\relax}\the\everycr}
\def\columncolor#1{{\def\current@color{#1}%
                    \csname a:cell-colortbl\endcsname}}
\Odef\columncolor[#1]#2{{\if :#1:\def\current@color{#2}%
                         \else
                           \gHAdvance\tblcol:N by 1
                           \convertcolorspec{#1}{#2}{HTML}\tmp:tblcolor
                           \Configure{HColor}{tblcol-\tblcol:N}{\#\tmp:tblcolor}%
                           \def\current@color{tblcol-\tblcol:N}%
                         \fi
                    \csname a:cell-colortbl\endcsname}%
   \futurelet\:temp\left:colcol}
\def\left:colcol{%
   \ifx [\:temp \expandafter\left::colcol \fi
}
\def\left::colcol[#1]{
   \futurelet\:temp\right:colcol
}
\def\right:colcol{%
   \ifx [\:temp \expandafter\right::colcol \fi
}
\def\right::colcol[#1]{}
\HAssign\tblcol:N = 0
\def\CT@cellc#1[#2]#3{{\if :#2:\def\current@color{#3}%
                         \else
                           \gHAdvance\tblcol:N by 1
                           \convertcolorspec{#2}{#3}{HTML}\tmp:tblcolor
                           \Configure{HColor}{tblcol-\tblcol:N}{\#\tmp:tblcolor}%
                           \def\current@color{tblcol-\tblcol:N}%
                         \fi
                    \csname a:cell-colortbl\endcsname}%
   \futurelet\:temp\left:colcol}
\NewConfigure{@classz}{4}
\pend:def\@classz{\pic:gobble\a:@classz}
\append:def\@classz{\pic:gobble\b:@classz}
\pend:def\insert@column{\pic:gobble\c:@classz}
\append:def\insert@column{\pic:gobble\d:@classz}
\def\:temp{\global\let\CT@do@color\relax}
\HLet\CT@@do@color\:temp
\let\::maketitle\o:maketitle:
\def\o:maketitle:{%
   \ifx \EndPicture\:UnDef
      \NewConfigure{@classz}{4}%
      \Configure{@classz}{}{}{}{}%
   \fi
   \::maketitle }
\def\rowcolor{%
  \o:noalign:{\ifnum0=`}\fi
  \global\let\CT@do@color\CT@@do@color
  \relax
\ifx\LT@head\Un:Def\else
   \ifnum \HRow=0\relax
      \expandafter\ifx\csname lt:sv\endcsname\relax
        \HAssign\HRow = 1\relax
        \ifvoid\LT@head
           \ifvoid\LT@firsthead \else \HAdvance\HRow by 1\relax\fi
        \else \HAdvance\HRow by 1\relax\fi
      \else
        \HAssign\HRow = \lt:sv \relax
        \HAdvance\HRow by 1\relax
      \fi
\fi\fi
%
  \@ifnextchar[\CT@rowa\CT@rowb}
\def\CT@rowa[#1]#2{%
  \save:color#1 #2//%
  \pic:gobbleII\a:rowcolor{#2}%
  \gdef\CT@row@color{\CT@color{#2}}%
  \CT@rowc}
\def\CT@rowb#1{%
  \pic:gobbleII\a:rowcolor{#1}%
  \gdef\CT@row@color{\CT@color{#1}}%
  \CT@rowc}
\NewConfigure{rowcolor}{1}
% default hline color is black
\def\hline:color{000}
% save rule color in format usable in CSS
\newcommand\tmp:arrayrulecolor[2][named]{%
\ifvoid\@arstrutbox% test if we are inside a tabular environment
\convertcolorspec{#1}{#2}{HTML}\:tmp\global\let\hline:color\:tmp% we are not
\else%
\noalign{\convertcolorspec{#1}{#2}{HTML}\:tmp\global\let\hline:color\:tmp}% we are
\fi
}
\HLet\arrayrulecolor\tmp:arrayrulecolor
\def\convert:colorspec#1 #2 #3 #4{%
  \edef\current:color{%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax\else%
    #1\ifx\relax#2\relax\else%
    , #2\ifx\relax#3\relax\else%
      , #3\ifx\relax#4\relax\else%
        , #4%
        \fi%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  }%
}

\def\save:color#1 #2//{%
  \convert:colorspec#2 {} {} {} {}
  \convertcolorspec{#1}{\current:color}{HTML}\tmp:col
  \def\current@color{#2}
  \Configure{HColor}{\current@color}{\#\tmp:col}
}

\def\begin:current@color{\let\sv:curcolor\current@color}
\def\end:current@color{%
   \ifx \current@color\sv:curcolor
   \else%
   \expandafter\save:color\current@color//%
   \csname a:text-colortbl\endcsname
   \fi
}
\NewConfigure{text-colortbl}{1}
\def\GET@column@color{}
\def\color:ii[#1]#2#3!*?: {\def\:temp{#1 #2}}
\def\color:i#1#2!*?: {\def\:temp{#1}}
\let\ctbl:mcol\multicolumn
\def\multicolumn#1#2#3{%
   \ctbl:mcol{#1}{#2}{#3}%
   \expand:after{\expandafter\MUL:LMN\meaning\@preamble}\MUL:PA//%
   \ignorespaces}
{
  \def\MUL:PA{\gdef\MUL:PA}
  \def\MUL:LMN{%
  \catcode`\C=12
  \catcode`\T=12
  \catcode`\@=12
  \catcode`\c=12
  \catcode`\o=12
  \catcode`\l=12
  \catcode`\r=12
  \catcode`\t=12
  \catcode`\e=12
  \catcode`\m=12
  \catcode`\p=12
  \catcode`\d=12
  \catcode`\i=12
  \catcode`\b=12
  \gdef\MUL:LMN}
  \MUL:LMN#1CT@color #2@tempdimb#3//{\::KOLOR{#2}}
  \MUL:PA{CT@color @tempdimb}
}
\def\::KOLOR#1{\if :#1:\else \:KOLOR#1//%
\fi}
\def\:KOLOR{\@ifnextchar[\mc:clr{\mc:clr[]}}
{
  \catcode`\{=12
  \catcode`\}=12
  \catcode`\(=1
  \catcode`\)=2
  \gdef\mc:clr[#1]{#2}((%
       \def\current@color(\if :#1:\else #1 \fi #2)%
       \csname a:cell-colortbl\endcsname
     )\def\:temp##1//()\:temp)
)
\NewConfigure{cell-colortbl}{1}

   
\Hinput{colortbl}
\endinput
```

There is also an issue caused by use of `\textbf` inside `\caption`. Try this version of `nameref.4ht`:

```
% nameref.4ht (2022-06-27-13:57), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2005-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2022 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2022-06-27-13:57}

   \let\NR:Type\relax
\let\ltx@label\label
\def\prf:label{{\ifx \NR:Title\:UnDef \else \NR:Title\fi}%
               {\ifx \NR:Type\relax \else \NR:Type .1\fi}{}}%
\let\NR:StartSec\:StartSec
\let\NR:no@sect\no@sect
\def\no@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{\gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#7}}%
    \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
    \NR:no@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[{#7}]{#8}}
\def\:StartSec#1#2#3{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#3}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
   \NR:StartSec{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}

\def\:tempc#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#7}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
   \o:NR@sect:{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[{#7}]{#8}}
\HLet\NR@sect\:tempc

\def\:tempc#1#2#3#4#5{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel\ssect:ttl}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
   \o:NR@ssect:{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
}
\HLet\NR@ssect\:tempc

\def\:tempc[#1]#2{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{part}%
   \o:no@part:[{#1}]{#2}}

% this definition clashes with asmart and amsproc classes, so we
% need to skip if these are active
\@ifundefined{opt@amsart.cls}{%
\@ifundefined{opt@amsproc.cls}{%
\HLet\no@part\:tempc
}{}}{}


\def\:tempc#1{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{part}%
   \o:no@spart:{#1}}
\HLet\no@spart\:tempc

\def\:tempc[#1]#2{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{chapter}%
   \o:NR@chapter:[{#1}]{#2}}
\HLet\NR@chapter\:tempc

\def\:tempc#1{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel\sch:ttl}%
   \o:NR@schapter:{#1}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{chapter}%
}
\HLet\NR@schapter\:tempc

\let\o:NR@@caption\@caption
%
%
% Keith Andrews <kandrews@iicm.edu> reported that \@captype as
% \NR:Type threw an undefined control sequence error. I think
% \@currenvir is safe, there is nothing special about \@captype.
%
% use of \index and \label inside caption results in a fatal error
% we need to disable them in \NR:Title
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]{%
    \gdef\NR:Type{\@currenvir}%
    \begingroup%
    \let\index\:gobble%
    \let\label\:gobble%
    \protected@xdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#2}}%
    \endgroup%
   \o:NR@@caption{#1}[{#2}]%
}

\let\o:NRorg@opargbegintheorem\@opargbegintheorem
  \def\@opargbegintheorem#1#2#3{%
    \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#3}}%
    \gdef\NR:Type{\@currenvir}%
    \NR@gettitle{#3}%
    \defineautorefname{\@currenvir}{#1}%
    \o:NRorg@opargbegintheorem{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%

\let\o:NRorg@begintheorem\@begintheorem
  \def\@begintheorem#1#2{%
    \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1 #2}}%
    \gdef\NR:Type{\@currenvir}%
    \defineautorefname{\@currenvir}{#1}%
    \NR@gettitle{}%
    \o:NRorg@begintheorem{#1}{#2}%
  }%

% I don't know if this was useful for anything
% but we cannot use it anymore
% \AtBeginDocument{%
\@ifpackageloaded{listings}{%
      \def\:tempc#1{%
         \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{listing}}%
         \gdef\NR:Type{lstlisting}%
         \o:NROrg@lst@MakeCaption:{#1}%
         \gdef\@currentlabelname{listing}}
      \HLet\NROrg@lst@MakeCaption\:tempc
}{}%
  % bug [348]
\def\:tempams{%
    \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{equation}}%
    \gdef\NR:Type{equation}%
    \gdef\@currentlabelname{equation}%
}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581856/2891
\@ifpackageloaded{caption}{
  \pend:defIII\caption@beginex{%
    \gdef\NR:Type{\@currenvir}%
    \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{##2}}%
  }
}{}


\@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}{%
     \Configure{@begin}{align}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{multline}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{equation}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{boxed}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{equations}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{equation}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{gather*}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{gather}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{genfrac}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{measure@}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{multline*}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{multline}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{overset}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{smallmatrix}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{split}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{subarray}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{substack}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{underset}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{xleftarrow}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{xrightarrow}{\:tempams}
  }{
     \Configure{@begin}{equation}{\:tempams}
}

\let\T:ref=\::ref
\def\::ref{\@ifstar{\protect\T@ref}{\protect\T@ref}}
\def\T@ref#1{%
  \@safe@activestrue
  \let\::ref \T:ref
  \expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@firstoffive{#1}%
  \def\::ref{\@ifstar{\protect\T@ref}{\protect\T@ref}}
  \@safe@activesfalse
}

\gdef\defineautorefname#1#2{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname #1autorefname\endcsname{#2}}
\defineautorefname{theorem}{Theorem}

\Configure{newlabel}
   {\csname cur:th\endcsname \csname :currentlabel\endcsname}
   {\string\csname\space :autoref\string\endcsname
     {\NR:Type}#1}

\ifx \@currentlabelname\:UnDef
   \let\@currentlabelname\empty
\fi

\pend:defIII\@setref{\edef\RefArg{##3}}
\append:defIII\@setref{\let\:autoref\:gobble}
\let\:autoref\:gobble


\Hinput{nameref}
\endinput
```

And your document then looks like this:

[image]

Comment: @michal.21: I have getting `[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Index.tex  862      Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Index.tex  37       Paragraph ended before \@caption was complete.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./index.aux  18       Paragraph ended before \n:wlbl was complete.`. But not showing any issues when using `pdflatex`. It's only `make4ht`

Comment: @Balaji this is caused by the fix for `\index` inside `\caption`. See the updated answer for fixed `nameref.4ht`.

Comment: Now its working fine. But when using `-f jats` option `xml` is generating with `utf` characters. I have need `xml` is getting with `unicode entities like &#x002A;`. How to do this?

Comment: @Balaji why do you need this? it isn't easily possible due to the fact that LuaXML encodes most entities as Unicode characters.

Comment: I would like to convert `xml` to `epub` format using `tex4ebook`. So that requirement is needed for me.

Comment: @Balaji you don't need entities even in `epub`. but if you really want it, I can try to add support for this to LuaXML. preferably as a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your support and please find the new question like is <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649805/make4ht-output-xml-format-with-entities-is-hexadecimal-value>.