# Make4ht Output XML format with entities is hexadecimal value

Tags: luatex, make4ht

How to get all the special characters like `\nabla` should be `xml entity(&#x2207;)` format instead of direct `utf` characters?

My Mwe is :

```
\documentclass{acm-book}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,hyperref,listings,xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[inactive]{fancytooltips}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\begin{document}

\chapter{What is {\textquotedblleft}Software{\textquotedblright}?}

Furthermore, legacy software systems are notoriously difficult to replace. As noted experienced by this author as a chief information officer, legacy systems take considerable effort and money to replace and tend to be built upon, rather than replaced. So, those working on systems for complex organizations are likely to have to deal with these existing software systems. US Social Security Administration still dependencies on legacy software further entrenches its use. Other systems used by the US government have software sub-systems

\begin{align}
   IR_{\text{max(sec)}} = \frac{B}{\beta} \{\max_x\{H(X) - H(X|Y)\}\}
\end{align}

\noindent where $C$ denotes the concentration of molecules, $D$ is the diffusion coefficient of medium given by $D = K_BT/6\pi\eta r_m$, $\nabla^2$ denotes the squared-differential operator given in Cartesian coordinates $\{x,y,z\}$, $\nabla^2 = i\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + j\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} + k\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}$, $T$ is the temperature of operation degree Kelvin, $\eta$ is the viscosity of the medium, $r_m$ is the radius of the information molecule and $K_B$ is the Boltzmann constant.

When reusing existing software, it is wise to evaluate the relevance of the techniques and assumptions that were used in building that original software. This book focuses on software as a technology and how it has evolved over time. We will look at the trends, important innovations, and events, as well as the ever-broadening world of software.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that LuaXML, which is used for post-processing of the XML file, converts almost everything to Unicode text, even if you used XML entities. You need to use a modified version of the DOM serializing function to convert these characters to entities. But honestly, I don't understand why you would like to use entities instead of UTF-8 characters in 2022. It seems like a strange requirement.

Anyway, try this file, `build.lua`:

```lua
-- local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"


local codes = utf8.codes
local uchar = utf8.char
local escapes = {
  [">"] = "&gt;",
  ["<"] = "&lt;",
  ["&"] = "&amp;",
  ['"'] = "&quot;",
  ["'"] = "&#39;",
  ["`"] = "&#x60;"
}


local escape_element = function(text)
  local t = {}
  for _, codepoint in codes(text) do
    if codepoint > 128 then
      t[#t+1] = string.format("&#x%x;", codepoint) 
    else
      local char = uchar(codepoint)
      t[#t+1] =  char -- escapes[char] or char
    end
  end
  local result = table.concat(t)
  return result
end

-- this is a copy of serializing stuff from luaxml-domobject.lua
local void = {area = true, base = true, br = true, col = true, hr = true, img = true, input = true, link = true, meta = true, param = true}

local escapes = {
  [">"] = "&gt;",
  ["<"] = "&lt;",
  ["&"] = "&amp;",
  ['"'] = "&quot;",
  ["'"] = "&#39;",
  ["`"] = "&#x60;"
}

local function escape(search, text)
  return text:gsub(search, function(ch)
    return escapes[ch] or ""
  end)
end


local function escape_attr(text)
  return escape("([<>&\"'`])", text)
end

local actions = {
  TEXT = {text = "%s"},
  COMMENT = {start = "<!-- ", text = "%s", stop = " -->"},
  ELEMENT = {start = "<%s%s>", stop = "</%s>", void = "<%s%s />"},
  DECL = {start = "<?%s %s?>"},
  PI = {start = "<?%s %s?>"},
  DTD = {start = "<!DOCTYPE ", text = "%s" , stop=">"},
  CDATA = {start = "<![CDATA[", text = "%s", stop ="]]>"}
  
}

--- It serializes the DOM object back to the XML.
-- This function is mainly used for internal purposes, it is better to
-- use the `DOM_Object:serialize()`.
-- @param parser DOM object
-- @param current Element which should be serialized
-- @param level 
-- @param output
-- @return table Table with XML strings. It can be concenated using table.concat() function to get XML string corresponding to the DOM_Object.
local function serialize_dom(parser, current,level, output)
  local output = output or {}
  local function get_action(typ, action)
    local ac = actions[typ] or {}
    local format = ac[action] or ""
    return format
  end
  local function insert(format, ...)
    table.insert(output, string.format(format, ...))
  end
  local function prepare_attributes(attr)
    local t = {}
    local attr = attr or {}
    for k, v in pairs(attr) do
      t[#t+1] = string.format("%s='%s'", k, escape_attr(v))
    end
    -- sort attributes alphabetically. this will ensure that
    -- their order will not change between several executions of dom:serialize()
    table.sort(t)
    if #t == 0 then return "" end
    -- add space before attributes
    return " " .. table.concat(t, " ")
  end
  local function start(typ, el, attr)
    local format = get_action(typ, "start")
    insert(format, el, prepare_attributes(attr))
  end
  local function text(typ, text)
    local format = get_action(typ, "text")
    insert(format, escape_element(text))
  end
  local function stop(typ, el)
    local format = get_action(typ, "stop")
    insert(format,el)
  end
  local level = level or 0
  local spaces = string.rep(" ",level)
  local root= current or parser._handler.root
  local name = root._name or "unnamed"
  local xtype = root._type or "untyped"
  local text_content = root._text or ""
  local attributes = root._attr or {}
  -- if xtype == "TEXT" then
  --   print(spaces .."TEXT : " .. root._text)
  -- elseif xtype == "COMMENT" then
  --   print(spaces .. "Comment : ".. root._text)
  -- else
  --   print(spaces .. xtype .. " : " .. name)
  -- end
  -- for k, v in pairs(attributes) do
  --   print(spaces .. " ".. k.."="..v)
  -- end
  if xtype == "DTD" then
    text_content = string.format('%s %s "%s" "%s"', name, attributes["_type"] or "",  attributes._name, attributes._uri )
    -- remove unused fields
    text_content = text_content:gsub('"nil"','')
    text_content = text_content:gsub('%s*$','')
    attributes = {}
  elseif xtype == "ELEMENT" and void[name] and #current._children < 1 then
    local format = get_action(xtype, "void")
    insert(format, name, prepare_attributes(attributes))
    return output
  elseif xtype == "PI" then
    -- it contains spurious _text attribute
    attributes["_text"] = nil
  elseif xtype == "DECL" and name =="xml" then
    -- the xml declaration attributes must be in a correct order
    local encoding = attributes.encoding or "utf-8"
    insert("<?xml version='%s' encoding='%s' ?>", attributes.version, encoding)
    return output
  elseif xtype == "CDATA" then
    -- return content unescaped
    insert("<![CDATA[%s]]>", text_content)
    return output
  end

  start(xtype, name, attributes)
  text(xtype,text_content) 
  local children = root._children or {}
  for _, child in ipairs(children) do
    output = serialize_dom(parser,child, level + 1, output)
  end
  stop(xtype, name)
  return output
end



local process = filter {
  function(text)
    local dom = domobject.parse(text)
    return table.concat(serialize_dom(dom))
  end
}

-- trick to insert this filter to the end
Make:match("xml$", function()
  Make:match("xml$", process)
end)
```

Most of it's code is a copy of the serializing function from `luaxml-domobject.lua`. We just changed one function, `escape_element`, to convert characters to entities:

```lua
local escape_element = function(text)
  local t = {}
  for _, codepoint in codes(text) do
    if codepoint > 128 then
      t[#t+1] = string.format("&#x%x;", codepoint) 
    else
      local char = uchar(codepoint)
      t[#t+1] =  char -- escapes[char] or char
    end
  end
  local result = table.concat(t)
  return result
end
```

There is also one necessary trick. You want to execute this filter as the last one, as further DOM filters would convert entities back to characters. This can be achieved using this code:

```lua
-- trick to insert this filter to the end
Make:match("xml$", function()
  Make:match("xml$", process)
end)
```

There is also another issue. The current configuration for JATS in TeX4ht can fail for some MathML code. I've fixed it in the sources. Before you get an TeX Live update, you can use this file, `tex4ht.usr`, which ensures correct conversion:

```
\Configure{jats}{%
   \Hinclude[*]{html4.4ht}% we will build upon HTML
   \Hinclude[*]{jats.4ht}%
   \Hinclude[*]{mathml.4ht}%
   \Hinclude[*]{html-mml.4ht}%
   \Hinclude[*]{unicode.4ht}%
}
```

This is the result:

```xml
<label>Chapter&#xa0;1</label><title id='x1-10001'> What is &#x201c;Software&#x201d;?</title>
```