\nameref and \@currentlabelname don't work with tex4ht
I would like to be able to use \nameref and \@currentlabelname with tex4ht. Consider the following example file:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{mylabelcounter}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\@currentlabelname{current label name}
\refstepcounter{mylabelcounter}
\label{mylabel}
\makeatother
Labelled text.

Link to labelled text: \nameref{mylabel}

\end{document}

When I compile this with pdflatex, I get the expected result of:
Labelled text.

Link to labelled text: current label name

However, when I compile with make4ht I get:
Labelled text.

Link to labelled text: 

It seems like the following link describes a similar problem, but I don't understand what the resolution was.
https://comp.text.tex.narkive.com/3RkBBAuf/tex4ht-can-t-handle-nameref

tex4ht supports nameref only for some standard commands like sections and captions. You could try \ExpandArgs{c}\gdef{NR:Title}{\UseName{a:newlabel}{\@currentlabelname}} after your @currentlabelname definition.

As Ulrike said, Nameref support doesn't work out of the box. We need to create a configuration for all supported commands. In your case, I would create a command that will create your labelled text:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{mylabelcounter}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mytextlabel[1]{%
\def\@currentlabelname{#1}
\refstepcounter{mylabelcounter}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\mytextlabel{current label name}
\label{mylabel}
Labelled text.

Link to labelled text: \nameref{mylabel}

\end{document}

You can then redefine \mytextlabel to insert necessary code for TeX4ht in a config file:
\Preamble{xhtml}
\catcode`\:=11
\def\:tempa#1{
  \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1}}%
  \o:mytextlabel:{#1}
}
\HLet\mytextlabel\:tempa
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble

The important line is this: \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1}}%. It will save the referenced value and make it available in the next \label. Rest of the code just patches your original command.
Compile using:
$ make4ht -c config.cfg sample.tex

This is the result:

You can also simplify this a bit if you move the custom command to a package, mytextlabel.sty:
\ProvidesPackage{mytextlabel}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{mylabelcounter}
\newcommand\mytextlabel[1]{%
\def\@currentlabelname{#1}
\refstepcounter{mylabelcounter}
}

\endinput

You will need also the correspongind mytextlabel.4ht:
\def\:tempa#1{
  \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1}}%
  \o:mytextlabel:{#1}
}
\HLet\mytextlabel\:tempa

Edit:
I've also found that we can use \@currentlabelname in TeX4ht. Try this version of nameref.4ht. It works with your original code:
% nameref.4ht (2022-12-30-15:46), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2005-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2022 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2022-12-30-15:46}

   \let\NR:Type\relax
\let\ltx@label\label
\def\prf:label{{\ifx \NR:Title\:UnDef \a:newlabel{\@currentlabelname}\else \NR:Title\fi}%
               {\ifx \NR:Type\relax \else \NR:Type .1\fi}{}}%

\append:defI\label{\let\NR:Title\undefined}

\let\NR:StartSec\:StartSec
\let\NR:no@sect\no@sect
\def\no@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{\gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#7}}%
    \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
    \NR:no@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[{#7}]{#8}}
\def\:StartSec#1#2#3{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#3}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
   \NR:StartSec{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}

\def\:tempc#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#7}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
   \o:NR@sect:{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[{#7}]{#8}}
\HLet\NR@sect\:tempc

\def\:tempc#1#2#3#4#5{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel\ssect:ttl}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
   \o:NR@ssect:{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
}
\HLet\NR@ssect\:tempc

\def\:tempc[#1]#2{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{part}%
   \o:no@part:[{#1}]{#2}}

% this definition clashes with asmart and amsproc classes, so we
% need to skip if these are active
\@ifundefined{opt@amsart.cls}{%
\@ifundefined{opt@amsproc.cls}{%
\HLet\no@part\:tempc
}{}}{}


\def\:tempc#1{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{part}%
   \o:no@spart:{#1}}
\HLet\no@spart\:tempc

\def\:tempc[#1]#2{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{chapter}%
   \o:NR@chapter:[{#1}]{#2}}
\HLet\NR@chapter\:tempc

\def\:tempc#1{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel\sch:ttl}%
   \o:NR@schapter:{#1}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{chapter}%
}
\HLet\NR@schapter\:tempc

\let\o:NR@@caption\@caption
%
%
% Keith Andrews <kandrews@iicm.edu> reported that \@captype as
% \NR:Type threw an undefined control sequence error. I think
% \@currenvir is safe, there is nothing special about \@captype.
%
% use of \index and \label inside caption results in a fatal error
% we need to disable them in \NR:Title

% there can be more problematic commands, so we provide a configuration
% that can be used multiple times - the default value fixes known commands
% but a user can add more of them

\def\a:captioncommandsfix{}
\NewConfigure{CaptionCommandsFix}[1]{\concat:config\a:captioncommandsfix{#1}}
\Configure{CaptionCommandsFix}{
  \let\index\:gobble%
  \let\label\:gobble%
  \let\\\relax% causes issues when \centering is active
}

\long\def\@caption#1[#2]{%
    \gdef\NR:Type{\@currenvir}%
    \begingroup%
    \a:captioncommandsfix
    \protected@xdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#2}}%
    \endgroup%
   \o:NR@@caption{#1}[{#2}]%
}

\let\o:NRorg@opargbegintheorem\@opargbegintheorem
  \def\@opargbegintheorem#1#2#3{%
    \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#3}}%
    \gdef\NR:Type{\@currenvir}%
    \NR@gettitle{#3}%
    \defineautorefname{\@currenvir}{#1}%
    \o:NRorg@opargbegintheorem{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%

\let\o:NRorg@begintheorem\@begintheorem
  \def\@begintheorem#1#2{%
    \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1 #2}}%
    \gdef\NR:Type{\@currenvir}%
    \defineautorefname{\@currenvir}{#1}%
    \NR@gettitle{}%
    \o:NRorg@begintheorem{#1}{#2}%
  }%

% I don't know if this was useful for anything
% but we cannot use it anymore
% \AtBeginDocument{%
\@ifpackageloaded{listings}{%
      \def\:tempc#1{%
         \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{listing}}%
         \gdef\NR:Type{lstlisting}%
         \o:NROrg@lst@MakeCaption:{#1}%
         \gdef\@currentlabelname{listing}}
      \HLet\NROrg@lst@MakeCaption\:tempc
}{}%
  % bug [348]
\def\:tempams{%
    \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{equation}}%
    \gdef\NR:Type{equation}%
    \gdef\@currentlabelname{equation}%
}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581856/2891
\@ifpackageloaded{caption}{
  \pend:defIII\caption@beginex{%
    \gdef\NR:Type{\@currenvir}%
    % handle \label and \index in Caption's package
    % version of \caption
    \begingroup%
    \a:captioncommandsfix
    \protected@xdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{##2}}%
    \endgroup%
  }
}{}


\@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}{%
     \Configure{@begin}{align}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{multline}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{equation}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{boxed}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{equations}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{equation}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{gather*}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{gather}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{genfrac}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{measure@}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{multline*}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{multline}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{overset}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{smallmatrix}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{split}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{subarray}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{substack}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{underset}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{xleftarrow}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{xrightarrow}{\:tempams}
  }{
     \Configure{@begin}{equation}{\:tempams}
}

\let\T:ref=\::ref
\def\::ref{\@ifstar{\protect\T@ref}{\protect\T@ref}}
\def\T@ref#1{%
  \@safe@activestrue%
  \let\::ref\T:ref%
  \expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@firstoffive{#1}%
  \def\::ref{\@ifstar{\protect\T@ref}{\protect\T@ref}}%
  \@safe@activesfalse%
}

\gdef\defineautorefname#1#2{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname #1autorefname\endcsname{#2}}
\defineautorefname{theorem}{Theorem}

\Configure{newlabel}
   {\csname cur:th\endcsname \csname :currentlabel\endcsname}
   {\string\csname\space :autoref\string\endcsname
     {\NR:Type}#1}

\ifx \@currentlabelname\:UnDef
   \let\@currentlabelname\empty
\fi

\pend:defIII\@setref{\edef\RefArg{##3}}
\append:defIII\@setref{\let\:autoref\:gobble}
\let\:autoref\:gobble


\Hinput{nameref}
\endinput



Thanks for the answer. Would it be "safe" to do something like this instead?
\let\oldlabel\label
\renewcommand\label[1]{\ExpandArgs{c}\gdef{NR:Title}{\UseName{a:newlabel}{\@currentlabelname}}\oldlabel{#1}}

(I tried the above code but put inside a "AtBeginDocument", and it was also able to get my desired result, but I'm wondering whether it is likely that I will run into problems by doing this)

@Daniel I wouldn't redefine \label in this way, because you wouldn't be able to reference to any other reference type, like sections, equations etc. But you can add another argument for \mytextlabel and put \label inside it.

why doesn't make4ht use  \@currentlabelname?

@UlrikeFischer good question. I investigate a bit and it seems that it should be possible to use it.
